# Firebase Codelab Friendlychat Android Apps: how to get image instead of text

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I send an image from the web app to my android app but i found the app crash immediately as soon as it gets the data. Your demo only showcase a simple text transaction between apps-web and android, but how about for the image what variables in the firebase class that I need to pay attention to? I need to display the image transferred to the text view. Does firebase has library to facilitate this? would you show some code example for easier understanding. I refer the code downloaded from this address https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat for your reference.

Comment: i can already manage to get the image url by using friendlyMessage.getImageUrl(). But after using the Glide function to load the image, it still fail to pop out the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found good reference for the study guide at https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files

The most simplest way i can even just use the ImageView to console out the image (.png, gif,jpeg, etc) in android. Here's the code tested,

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                        storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(friendlyMessage.getImageUrl());//storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://<your-bucket-name>");
                        Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                                .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                                .load(storageRef)
                                .into(viewHolder.ivMessageImage);
```

Thx for the excellent view and attention from firebase support!

Comment: I upvoted 5 star for the documentation in the link. ;-)